# Taking ownership for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, permissions

I'm new to SQL Server 2008. I just installed SQL Server Express. I'm having trouble creating a new database, and I think I don't have permission.

I login like this, please see this screenshot:

[image]

Then I tried to create a new database and I got this:

[image]

I tried to search for some solution and this what I've got:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/02/23/how-to-take-ownership-of-your-local-sql-server-2008-express.aspx

But I can't download the script and the page says:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

Please help. Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my problem with the following steps:

Set the instance of the SQL Service to single-user mode:

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager. Double click SQL Server Services.
- Stop all SQL Server services

[image]

- Right click SQL service and click Properties, in the Advanced tab, look for 'Startup Parameters'

[image]

- Insert '-m;' at the beginning of the Startup Parameters value

[image]

- Start the SQL service
- Open SQL Server Management Studio and login with Windows authentication, you can now add user or change password of different users.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with the `sa` account and grant permissions to your Windows account.

If you do not know the `sa` password use `sqlcmd` and execute the following commands:

```
Use Master
Go

ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'NewPassword'
Go
```

Login with the `sa` account and `GRANT` permission to the account.

```
USE Master;
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO Jommel;
```

Comment: I tried it in sqlcmd and I got this: "Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission"

Comment: sqlcmd –S SQLSERVER\INSTANCE, i don't know the instance